# Maintain Cross reference in SAP-MDG

Tags: sap-erp, master-data-management

I am new to SAP Master Data Governance and I am trying to identify how can we store cross reference details in MDG.

I got to know about key mapping but that is not something that I understand.

**My requirement is:**
I have 10 applications sending data to me each having it's own app id and customer number, I want to store the mapping.

App -id  ---   Customer number from application ---- sap-id(at our end)

Is this something that can be done without a custom table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better place for get answers for your questions - sdn.sap.com (sap mdg community)

1. you can create this table like a data model (for example via reuse method) and save it in staging area sap mdg
2. you can use Z-table for store this data

Comment: Thank you! I am doing the same thing, have created a ZTable and am using the reuse mode of extending the data model.